# What is this menu style called?

Tags: jquery, menu

I am trying to style a menu that has a static height and the content is displayed between the headers. (Please see below image. ...the right side is the view after a user clicks on Header 2)

What is this menu style called? How can I accomplish this with jQuery?

[image: accordion menu]

**Edit:** Thanks! I searched for accordion before asking, but I was unable to find any examples where the menu's height stays static regardless of the content.

**Edit 2:** This is the behavior I was looking for: [Vertical concertina menu](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/vertical-concertina.html) 
Thanks @ricebowl for providing the link.

Comment: It's worth pointing out, I think, that you can achieve this layout with just xhtml and css, no *necessity* (unless you want) to use jQuery or JS. See my answer below.

Comment: Sure, but usually clients are demanding nowadays and want pretty little effects and animation, I don't think a super minimalistic html/css would cut it for some clients.

Comment: @meder, you're absolutely right; but for those willing to live with basics, it's a good resource. But I like to make it work with the basics, and *enhance* with the JS/jQuery. That way it still looks good -if basic- without. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure you know, by now, that this is the accordion menu style, I'll just suggest -if you're amenable to a non-jQuery option- that you visit Stu Nicholl's [css-play](http://www.cssplay.co.uk) website, where he has a pure [xhtml/css version](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/gallery3l) of this accordion menu style.

Comment: Wow, that's actually pretty cool for not using a single line of script!

Comment: Thanks for the link! I found exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Gurdas, I've found Stu Nicholl's site to be indispensable over the years for learning new things and dealing with CSS problems. His css games, though, are *pure* awesome: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/ (under the heading 'Puzzles') =)

Answer (score 9):

This is known as an accordion menu.  [Here is a tutorial on how to create one using jQuery.](http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/jquery-accordion-menu/)

Answer (score 6):

It's called an accordion menu and it's available in jQuery UI:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Answer (score 1):

Vertical accordion menu

Answer (score 1):

This is accordion menu.

jQuery docs here:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/accordion

Answer (score 0):

this is called Accordion

Answer (score 0):

This is an Accordion Menu and is available as a widget in Jquery UI - http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the **Accordian Menu** UI pattern.  There are quite a few jQuery plugin implementations, including this one: [jQuery Accordion](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/accordion).

More info and some good examples here:

http://ui-patterns.com/pattern/AccordionMenu